# Sort List of Map: need to sort list of map based on two values at one go

Tags: java

Need to sort the list of map having string, Object entry as given below,

```
List<Map<String,Object>> listOfMap = new ArrayList<Map<String,Object>>();
// creating maps
Map<String, Object> map1 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
map1.put("Number", 2);
map1.put("Date1", new Date("12-OCT-2018"));// Consider any date
map1.put("Date2", new Date("02-MAY-2017"));// Consider any date

Map<String, Object> map2 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
map2.put("Number", 5);
map2.put("Date1", new Date("12-OCT-2018"));// Consider some date
map2.put("Date2", new Date("01-JAN-2017"));// Consider some date

// ...

Map<String, Object> mapN = new HashMap<String, Object>();
mapN.put("Number", 8);
mapN.put("Date1", new Date("10-JAN-2016"));// Consider some date
mapN.put("Date2", new Date("10-MAY-2016"));// Consider some date
```

With this above list of Map value, I need the below output by sorting based on date1 and date 2 at one stretch itself..

My Required order of O/p for the above input data is:

```
Number  Date1      Date2
8       10-Jan-16  10-May-16  //mapN 
5       12-Oct-18  1-Jan-17   //map2
2       12-Oct-18  2-May-17   //map1
```

Comment: Look up "Comparators" -- you need to write a comparator class that does your comparison of any two Maps, indicating their order by your rules. Then you can sort a list of such maps using that comparator.

Answer (score 1):

I'd encapsulate your map objects into a class. In fact, you may not need the map at all since I see you are using the same keys for every map (couldn't you use attributes of a class instead?).

Once you've this encapsulation, make that class implement the comparable interface, and in your compareTo method, compare using the criteria you need.

Doing this, all you need to do afterwards is using .sort() on your list.

EDIT: If you have to conserve the maps no matter what, make a class that

```
implements Comparator<Map<String, Object>>
```

where you compare your maps, and pass it as parameter to the .sort() method of the list.

Comment: This is the correct answer. If you ever find yourself with a `Map<K, Object>` i.e. a "map of stuff", you should seriously consider using a class. For starters, getting things out of the map is going to require all sorts of horrible error-prone casting.

Comment: Thanks, but I never tried Comparator, Could you please help me out how to write out an impl. to sort map with two fields date1, date2 in same comaprator impl.class

Answer (score 1):

This may help you:

```
List<Map<String,Object>> listOfMap = new ArrayList<Map<String,Object>>();
// creating maps
Map<String, Object> map1 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
map1.put("Number", 2);
map1.put("Date1", new Date("12-OCT-2018"));// Consider any date
map1.put("Date2", new Date("02-MAY-2017"));// Consider any date

Map<String, Object> map2 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
map2.put("Number", 5);
map2.put("Date1", new Date("12-OCT-2018"));// Consider some date
map2.put("Date2", new Date("01-JAN-2017"));// Consider some date

Map<String, Object> mapN = new HashMap<String, Object>();
mapN.put("Number", 8);
mapN.put("Date1", new Date("10-JAN-2016"));// Consider some date
mapN.put("Date2", new Date("10-MAY-2016"));// Consider some date

listOfMap.add(map1);
listOfMap.add(map2);
listOfMap.add(mapN);

Collections.sort(listOfMap, new Comparator<Map<String,Object>>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Map<String,Object> obj1, Map<String,Object> obj2 {
        Date obj1date1 = (Date) obj1.get("Date1");
        Date obj2date1 = (Date) obj2.get("Date1");
        if(obj1date1.compareTo(obj2date1)==0) {
            Date obj1date2 = (Date) obj1.get("Date2");
            Date obj2date2 = (Date) obj2.get("Date2");
            return obj1date2.compareTo(obj2date2);
        } else
            return obj1date1.compareTo(obj2date1);
    }
});

for(Map<String,Object> map : listOfMap)
    System.out.println(map.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

If you opt not to use an encapsulating class you could just use a lambda function to compare your entries:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> lst = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>();
lst.stream().sorted((map1, map2) -> {
    // compare the values here
    return 0;
}).forEachOrdered(map -> {/* output here */});
```

Of course you can use the lambda if you write an encapsulating class, too.